# Setting up Heroku with mongodb without using MLAB

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mlab

Most of the documentation Ive seen only covers using mLab as a service for mongodb on heroku,
I would like to use mongoDB locally on the heroku server is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku dynos use an ephemeral filesystem. This means that you cannot run a database on a Heroku dyno. All of the data will be lost whenever your process restarts. Your process restarts at least once every day, whenever you deploy new code, whenever you change config variables, or whenever you update add-ons.

You can read more about Heroku's ephemeral filesystem here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

You can read more about dyno restarts here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting

So you will have to use a Heroku Add-on or a third-party service to add persistence to your application.

This doesn't mean you have to use the mLab Add-on. If you have your own MongoDB database, you can still connect to that in your application. You can add the connection string as a [config variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) and connect to it in the same way you would connect to an mLab Add-on.